# pgfplots addplot 'domain' option overwrites/collides with axis 'domain' option

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a problem with domain specification in addplot which collides with domain specification in axis.

The code below plots the x axis as well as the function (expo) from 0.1 to 2. My desired behavior is that the axis is plotted from 0 to 2 and only the function from 0.1 to 2.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{expo}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#1)*exp(-x/#1)}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=5cm,width=10cm,no markers,samples=100,axis lines=left,domain=0:2,xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5},ytick={0,4,8},enlargelimits=false
    ]
        \addplot[domain=0.1:2,thick] {expo(0.1)} node[pos=0.7,pin=45:{$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\approx\SI{0.1}{\meter}$}] {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Does anybody know, how to obtain the desired behaviour?

Comment: It is always better to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `xmin=0, xmax=2` to specify the min/max of the axis:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{expo}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#1)*exp(-x/#1)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=5cm,width=10cm,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        axis lines=left,
        xmin=0, xmax=2,%     <---- This controls the axis min/max
        xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5},
        ytick={0,4,8},
        enlargelimits=false,
    ]
        \addplot[domain=0.1:2,thick] {expo(0.1)} node[pos=0.7,pin=45:{$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\approx\SI{0.1}{\meter}$}] {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately, I was unable to find it in the documentation of pgfplots: To me it seems, that it only describes the syntax of the axis environment as '\begin{axis}[options] ... \end{axis}'. However, there should be a list of the possible 'options'. Do you know if there is a way to find this systematically in the reference?

Comment: They are documented in the pgfplots manual. Typing `texdoc pgfplots` at a Unix shell prompt should retrieve the manual for you.